# PHP: Nested for loops to make an array

Tags: php, ajax, loops, for-loop

Today I made my first 'for-loop'. I am using Microsoft Graph API PHP and want to echo Calendar Events together with its attendees. Everything is working, however every Ajax Call is noticable slower. Did I take the fastest approach, or is it highly inefficient?

Thank you!

The call generates the following array of Events

```
    attendees: [{type: "required", status: {response: "none", time: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},…},…]
       0: {type: "required", status: {response: "none", time: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},…}
          emailAddress: {name: "Name", address: "Address"}
            address: "Address"
            name: "Name"
          status: {response: "none", time: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
          type: "required"
       1: {type: "required", status: {response: "none", time: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},…}
       2: {type: "required", status: {response: "declined", time: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},…}
    description: "description"
    end: "2020-10-02T11:00:00+02:00"
    organizer: "Organizer"
    start: "2020-10-02T09:00:00+02:00"
    title: "Title"
```

My PHP is as follows:

`$n = count($events);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $n;) {
      if (isset($events[$i])) {
          $eventArray[$i] = ([
            'uid' => $events[$i] - > getId(),
            'title' => $events[$i] - > getSubject(),
            'end' => Carbon::parse($events[$i] - > getEnd() - > getDateTime()) - > timezone('Europe/Amsterdam') - > toIso8601String(),
            'start' => Carbon::parse($events[$i] - > getStart() - > getDateTime()) - > timezone('Europe/Amsterdam') - > toIso8601String(),
            'description' => $events[$i] - > getBody() - > setContentType('text') - > getContent(),
            'organizer' => $events[$i] - > getOrganizer() - > getEmailAddress() - > getName(),
            'attendees' => array(),
        ]);
    }
    if (isset($events[$i])) {
        $z = count($events[$i] - > getAttendees());

        for ($j = 0; $j <= $z; $j++) {
            if (isset($events[$i] - > getAttendees()[$j]['emailAddress']['name'])) {
                $eventArray[$i]['attendees'][] = ($events[$i] - > getAttendees()[$j]['emailAddress']['name']);
            } else {
                $i++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
}

echo wp_json_encode(['events' => $eventArray]);`

Comment: This PHP code doesn't look right. Is this working and does what's shown here match what you have? The for loop statement doesn't look right and the closing square bracket after attendees doesn't have an opening bracket. It looks like code is missing between `$i  $events[$i]`

Comment: Also, does the query to get events use pagination? How many records are being returned for each call? I don't see anything immediately with the PHP code that would slow things down significantly, so my first guess would be to make sure the database query is optimized.

Comment: You are perfectly right. The <pre><code>eats  some of the code. I am trying to get the whole code visible.

Edit: now it's completely visible. And to be complete: The current code, does show indeed what's requested :)

Comment: Yes, the query is bound to a $Startdate & $Enddate. In this case one month. Between 20 and 30 events are being returned per Room, per Month. Each Event is an array of 7 items/values.

Comment: I'm not seeing a reason why it would slow at 20-30 records. Why two separate `isset($events[$i])` statements and not just one? One guess about the speed would be to see what is happening when you are calling getAttendees(). Maybe only calling that once and setting it to a variable to get the count and loop over might avoid some of the processing that's happening in that method. I also haven't worked with Microsoft Graph API, but you can double check rate limits. 20-30 records isn't much, but maybe you're hitting the API too often?